# How to get data from Facebook using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, google-chrome-extension

For using in a Chrome extension I need to get data from a FB page, namely the messages.

In code behind it's seen that the messages are loaded through Bigpipe, a snippet of JSON data is returned through `bigPipe.onPageletArrive` (which includes users ids, from whom I get messages, threads ids, snippets of conversations etc.).

Is there any possibility to get hold of the whole data returned?

(I thought of using Facebook Graph API, but this requires authentication token, which I'm not sure how users of my extension can get hold of.)

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
For those who can come around the same question, I finally found the solution by looking into Facebook POST queries. There one can find all the information needed.

Answer (score -1):

Should be a comment, I'm aware but let me know if this works for you http://restfb.com/